# When to use TableController<T> and when to use Custom DomainManager

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to figure out when does it make sense to have a custom domain manager. Initially, I tough that whenever we had a return type that was not of type `T` in `TableController<T>` that we needed to create a new Custom DomainManager.

However, in the sample app [Sport by Xamarin](https://github.com/xamarin/Sport/blob/master/Sport.Service/Controllers/AthleteController.cs#L50), their controller inherits from `TableController<Athlete>`, but their GET method returns `IQueryable<AthleteDto>`

```
public IQueryable<AthleteDto> GetAllAthletes()
{
     return ...;
}
```

NOTE: `AthleteDto` does inherit from `EntityData`

If this is allowed, then why would I go through the trouble of creating a new DomainManager?

Do I only need to create a new DomainManager if my return value does not inherit from `EntityData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new DomainManager for each kind of data source you are connecting to. For instance, there is a built in domain manager for Azure Table Storage and one for SQL Azure using Entity Framework.

Your data types need to inherit from `EntityData` or implement the interface `ITableData` in order to use `TableController<T>`. This is independent of the domain manager question.

In the case of the sample you referenced, it is allowed to use different types between the domain manager and the return type of the controller methods, but it can make the code more complicated. That is because the base class methods will return the DTO type, and you have to now convert to a different type. Note that both of the types `Athlete` and `AthleteDto` in that sample inherit from `EntityData`, since they both have the superclass [`AthleteBase`](https://github.com/xamarin/Sport/blob/master/Sport.Service/Data/AthleteBase.cs).